# Z-value missing in attribute table of shapefile from ASCII 3D to Feature Class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, feature-class, ascii, z-value

i'm trying to convert some *.xyz files into shapefiles but unfortunately it does't work out correctly! I use the tool "ASCII 3D to Feature Class" (ArcMap extension "3D Analyst") because I've read this is a good and easy way to do this. But for some reason the attribute table of the resulting shapefile does not contain the z-values:

[image: attribute table]

This is a problem because I want to generate a DTM out of the shapefiles.

Is there any solution for this? I've tried several options within the tool but without luck.

I don't think it's that important but for your information:
I have two different kind of *.xyz files which I can use representing the same area (2 meter grid width and variable grid width). they are build like this:

variable grid width:
(no header) - (2x space)x-value(4x space)y-value(5x space)z-value

2 meter grid width:
(no header) - (2x space)x-value(2x space)y-value(2x space)z-value

Comment: Check if Z-value embedded in shape, start editing and see if vertex has Z attribute in addition to XY

Comment: The Z values are stored in the shape.You can examine the features in ArcScene. There is no need to add a field in the the attribute table altough you can do that if you'd like: Arc Toolbox -> Data Management Tools -> Add XY Coordinates.  This tool will add XYZ fields to the attribute table.

Comment: Felix is correct, with Multipoint, the Z and M values are stored per-vertex, of which there may be thousands per multipoint feature, which is an aggregate geometry type. If you want to have Z values in the attribute table, use Point, not Multipoint, and then use Dan's answer to add the Z values to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FelixIP said in the comments, the Z values should be in there: the "Z" in the Shape type of "Multipoint ZM" indicates that your layer is z-enabled, so if you did the conversion from .XYZ to Shapefile correctly, your Z values are in there. It's just that Z values don't show up in a feature's attribute table by default, you need to add them manually. You can use the 3D Analyst [Add Z Information](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000005z000000) tool to do that if you want to check your data, but any of the ESRI tools which operate on Z values should work fine with your shapefile the way it is.

Comment: Multipoint is an aggregate geometry type, in which many thousands of vertices (points) are stored per row (multipoint). So it will not be possible to extract each Z value without first converting to Point.